# Nn algorithm that divides a single number three times Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an algorithm that divides a single number three times. 
I've created this code, but it for some reason it doesn't work and I've got no clue why.

Could some one give me insight into what i'm doing wrong?

HTML

```
<form id="frm1">
  Budget: <input id="budget" type="text" name="budget" value="110"><br>
  <br>

  Domestic: 
  <input id="low" type="text" name="low" value="20">%<br>
  <input id="lowresult" type="text" name="low" oninput="calculate()"><br>

  Continental:
  <input id="med" type="text" name="med" value="30">% <br>
  <input id="medresult" type="text" name="med" oninput="calculate()"><br>

  International:
  <input id="high" type="text" name="high" value="50">% <br>
  <input id="highresult" type="text" name="high" oninput="calculate()"><br>
  <br>

</form>
```

Javascript

```
function calculate() {

var budget = document.getElementById("budget").value;
var low = document.getElementById('low').value;
var med = document.getElementById('med').value;
var high = document.getElementById('high').value;

var lowResult = document.getElementById('lowresult');
var medResult = document.getElementById('medresult');
var highResult = document.getElementById('highresult');

var lowFinalResult = (budget /100)*low;
    lowResult.value = lowResult;

var medFinalResult = (budget /100)*med;
    medResult.value = medResult;

var highFinalResult = (budget /100)*high;
    highResult.value = highResult;


}
```

Comment: Can you please explain further what "doesn't work" means? What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Sorry, if it wasn't clear. I'm trying to input one amount into the "budget" input and then have it divided three times, by the value in "low,med,high" and the result shown in "lowresult, medresult, highresult"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adjust javascript

this

```
var lowFinalResult = (budget /100)*low;
    lowResult.value = lowFinalResult;
```

insetad of

```
var lowFinalResult = (budget /100)*low;
    lowResult.value = lowResult;
```

full code

```
function calculate() {

var budget = document.getElementById("budget").value;
var low = document.getElementById('low').value;
var med = document.getElementById('med').value;
var high = document.getElementById('high').value;

var lowResult = document.getElementById('lowresult');
var medResult = document.getElementById('medresult');
var highResult = document.getElementById('highresult');

var lowFinalResult = (budget /100)*low;
    lowResult.value = lowFinalResult;

var medFinalResult = (budget /100)*med;
    medResult.value = medFinalResult;

var highFinalResult = (budget /100)*high;
    highResult.value = highFinalResult;


}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! A very stupid thing to oversee. I'll accept it as an answer asap

Comment: take rest in knowing the fact you are not alone in making mistakes like this :)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote in the comment that you're "trying to input one amount into the 'budget' input". So I'd like to add that you do that `calculate()` in the budget input:

```
<form id="frm1">
  Budget: <input id="budget" type="text" name="budget" 
           value="110" oninput="calculate()"><br>
```

So the `oninput` attribute of the other `input`s can be removed.